# Typesetting a legend for a plot on a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code gives me the display that I want. (I know that the code could have been much more efficient with `foreach` commands.) I would like a more consistent code for the legend. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Two scatter plots are drawn.
%
%The axes are drawn.
\draw (0,0) -- (7,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
%
%Tick marks on the x-axis is drawn.
\draw ($(0.5,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(0.5,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(1.25,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(1.25,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(2,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(2,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(2.75,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(2.75,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(3.5,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(3.5,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(4.25,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(4.25,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(5,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(5,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(5.75,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(5.75,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(6.5,0) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(6.5,0) +(0,-2pt)$);
%
%Tick marks on the y-axis is drawn.
\draw ($(0,0) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,0) +(0,0)$);
\draw ($(0,0.5625) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,0.5625) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,1.125) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,1.125) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,1.6875) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,1.6875) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,2.25) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,2.25) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,2.8125) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,2.8125) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,3.375) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,3.375) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,3.9375) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,3.9375) +(2pt,0)$);
\draw ($(0,4.5) +(-2pt,0)$) -- ($(0,4.5) +(2pt,0)$);
%
%Horizontal lines are drawn in the first quadrant of the Cartesian plane.
\draw (0,0.5625) -- (7,0.5625);
\draw (0,1.125) -- (7,1.125);
\draw (0,1.6875) -- (7,1.6875);
\draw (0,2.25) -- (7,2.25);
\draw (0,2.8125) -- (7,2.8125);
\draw (0,3.375) -- (7,3.375);
\draw (0,3.9375) -- (7,3.9375);
\draw (0,4.5) -- (7,4.5);
%
%The label for the x-axis is typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(3.5,0) +(0,-0.65)$){Year};
%The label for the y-axis is typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, rotate=90] at ($(0,2.25) +(-1.25,0)$){Amount (US cents per lb)};
%
%The title for the plots is typeset.
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(3.5,0) +(0,4.75)$){Regular Coffee Profits\\Compared to Fair Trade Coffee\\Profits in Tanzania};
%
%Some tick marks along the x-axis are labeled.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0.5,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2000};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2002};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(3.5,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2004};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2006};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(6.5,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2008};
%Some tick marks along the y-axis are labeled.
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,0) +(-0.15,0)$){0};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,0.5625) +(-0.15,0)$){20};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,1.125) +(-0.15,0)$){40};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,1.6875) +(-0.15,0)$){60};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,2.25) +(-0.15,0)$){80};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,2.8125) +(-0.15,0)$){100};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,3.375) +(-0.15,0)$){120};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,3.9375) +(-0.15,0)$){140};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(0,4.5) +(-0.15,0)$){160};
%
%
%One of the two plots is drawn.
\draw ($(0.5,0) +(0,1.51875)$) -- ($(1.25,0) +(0,0.95625)$) -- ($(2,0) +(0,0.675)$) -- ($(2.75,0) +(0,0.675)$) -- ($(3.5,0) +(0,0.703125)$)
-- ($(4.25,0) +(0,1.18125)$) -- ($(5,0) +(0,1.153125)$) -- ($(5.75,0) +(0,1.659375)$) -- ($(6.5,0) +(0,1.74375)$);
\draw[fill] ($(0.5,0) +(0,1.51875)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(1.25,0) +(0,0.95625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(2,0) +(0,0.675)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(2.75,0) +(0,0.675)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(3.5,0) +(0,0.703125)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(4.25,0) +(0,1.18125)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(5,0) +(0,1.153125)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(5.75,0) +(0,1.659375)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ($(6.5,0) +(0,1.74375)$) circle (1.5pt);
%
%The other of the two plots is drawn.
\draw[dashed] ($(0.5,0) +(0,3.628125)$) -- ($(1.25,0) +(0,3.65625)$) -- ($(2,0) +(0,3.65625)$) -- ($(2.75,0) +(0,3.65625)$)
-- ($(3.5,0) +(0,3.65625)$) -- ($(4.25,0) +(0,3.65625)$) -- ($(5.75,0) +(0,3.65625)$) -- ($(6.5,0) +(0,3.853125)$);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(0.5,0) +(0,3.628125)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(1.25,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(2,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(2.75,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(3.5,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(4.25,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(5,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(5.75,0) +(0,3.65625)$) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white, thick] ($(6.5,0) +(0,3.853125)$) circle (1.5pt);
%
%
%The legend to the plots is typeset.
\draw (1.75,-1.25) -- (5.25,-1.25) --(5.25,-2.125) -- (1.75,-2.125) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] ($(1.75,-1.5) +(4pt,0)$) -- ($(1.75,-1.5) +(32pt,0)$);
\draw [fill=white, thick] ($(1.75,-1.5) +(18pt,0)$) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(1.75,-1.5) +(36pt,0)$){fair trade coffee}; 
\draw ($(1.75,-1.875) +(4pt,0)$) -- ($(1.75,-1.875) +(32pt,0)$);
\draw[fill]  ($(1.75,-1.875) +(18pt,0)$) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(1.75,-1.875) +(36pt,0)$){regular coffee}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}




\end{document}
```

Comment: why you not use `pgfplots` package and make your life more simple? where you like to have legend?

Answer (score 1):

see, if the following solution can help you in drawing of your diagram:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{% here should be real coffee price
                       % y1: regular coffee
                       % y2: fair trade coffee
        date    y1      y2
        2001    1.519   3.628
        2002    0.956   3.656
        2003    0.675   3.656
        2004    0.675   3.656
        2005    0.703   3.656
        2006    1.181   3.656
        2007    1.153   3.656
        2008    1.659   3.656
        2009    1.743   3.853
                    }\mydata
\begin{axis}[width=80mm,
grid,
tick label style = {font=\footnotesize,
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
xlabel = year,
ylabel = {Amount (US cents per lb)},
 title = {Profits\\ Compared to Fair Trade Coffee\\ Profits in Tanzania},
title style={at={(0.5,1)},
             text width=0.8\linewidth,
             align=center},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.16)},anchor=north},
legend cell align=left
            ]
% regular coffee
\addplot table[x=date, y=y1] {\mydata};
% fair trade coffee
\addplot table[x=date, y=y2] {\mydata};
%The legend
    \legend{regular coffee, fair trade coffee};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**note:**

- by use of the packet `pgfplots` the code for your image is significantly reduced, simplifies and far more clear
- for coffee prices i use given coordinates in your *mwe* (minimal working example), however is suspect that real prices are about forty times higher. so you need to check data in table `\mydata` and then correct them accordingly.
- if you like to have bigger or smaller diagram, just change option `width` from 80mm to desired width
- for document class i select `standalone` which is handy at drawing of images. however, you can replace it with `{amsart}`.
- for positioning of of image on the page don't use aproach as you show in your *mwe*. better is to enclose it in `\begin{center} ... tikzpicture ... \end{center}` or even better in float environment `figure`